# xmlConfig.configurationAt is not fetching value

Tags: java, xml-parsing, apache-commons

I have a xml something like this.

```
<card>
    <name>VISA</name>
    <id>0</id>
    <length>
        <value>16</value>
    </length>
    <bin>
        <range>
            <start>4</start>
        </range>
    </bin>
</card>
```

Here is my code that I am using to load this and parse this xml.

```
private XMLConfiguration loadInputXml(final String responseXml)
        throws ConfigurationException {
    final XMLConfiguration xmlConfig = new XMLConfiguration();
    xmlConfig.setDelimiterParsingDisabled(true);
    xmlConfig.setValidating(false);
    xmlConfig.load(new ByteArrayInputStream(responseXml.getBytes()));
    return xmlConfig;
}
```

Now I am trying to fetch the values by this code

```
XMLConfiguration xmlConfig = loadInputXml(xmlString);
List<HierarchicalConfiguration> cardList = xmlConfig
        .configurationsAt("card");
```

I am not able to fetch the child nodes and I am not getting any error therefore I am not able to find the root cause of it. 
Need help.
Thanks in advance!!!!

Comment: What should I use? I am first time using this.

Answer (score 1):

`xmlConfig.configurationAt` is not fetching any value because `card` is **the root element** of your `XML` so calling `configurationsAt("card")` will make it search for an element `card` inside your root element and here you have no such element so you get nothing.

For me what you try to do, doesn't make much sense but if for an unknown reason you really need to access to the root element with `configurationsAt` use rather an empty `String` as parameter to make it fetch the root element as next:

```
List<HierarchicalConfiguration> cardList = xmlConfig.configurationsAt("");
```

---

What you should rather do is simply use your instance of the class `XMLConfiguration` to access to your properties with one of the `getXXX` methods according to the expected type.

For example let's say that I want to get the value of the `name` and the `length`, I would proceed as next:

```
XMLConfiguration xmlConfig = ...
// Get as String the text content of the element name
String name = xmlConfig.getString("name");
// Get as int the text content of the element value of the first element length
int length = xmlConfig.getInt("length(0).value");
```